# Where do i add the include_null_values in this query with JSONB Array of Objects?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

here is my code

```
select "status" as "status", count("id")::integer as "id"
from (
 select arr.items_object ->> 'id' as id,
   arr.items_object ->> 'Pushed' as Pushed,
   arr.items_object ->> 'status' as status,
   arr.items_object ->> 'Category' as Category,
   arr.items_object ->> 'Customer' as Customer,
   arr.items_object ->> 'HotFixID' as HotFixID,
   arr.items_object ->> 'Location' as Location,
   arr.items_object ->> 'Severity' as Severity,
   arr.items_object ->> 'approved' as approved,
   arr.items_object ->> 'Installed' as Installed,
   arr.items_object ->> 'KB Article' as kb_article,
   arr.items_object ->> 'Machine ID' as machine_id,
   arr.items_object ->> 'Patch Name' as patch_name,
   (((arr.items_object ->> 'Queue Date')::jsonb) ->> 'Value')::timestamp as queue_date,
   (((arr.items_object ->> 'Install Date')::jsonb) ->> 'Value')::timestamp as install_date,
   arr.items_object ->> 'Machine Name' as machine_name,
   arr.items_object ->> 'Machine Type' as machine_type,
   (((arr.items_object ->> 'Finished Date')::jsonb) ->> 'Value')::timestamp as finished_date 
 from tenant_agent_data tad ,
   jsonb_array_elements(extend)  with ordinality arr(items_object, position)
 where tenant_code = 1308170522957828098 
   and sql_id = 51
) tdetail
where "queue_date" >=     (
  select (date_trunc('days', convert_timezonetz(NOW(), 'America/Chicago') - interval '30 days') at time zone      'America/Chicago'))
  and "queue_date" <     (
    select (date_trunc('days', convert_timezonetz(NOW(), 'America/Chicago') + interval '1 days') at time zone      'America/Chicago'))
group by "status"
```

thankyou in advance

Comment: Tag responsibly .   Pick the appropriate database

Comment: Formatting a SQL query with linebreaks and proper indention goes a long way in understanding the code.

Comment: Note that there is no need to prefix a function call with `select` so `queue_date >=   (select date_trunc(...))` can be simplified to `queue_date >= date_trunc(....)`

Comment: sorry about that i will moving forward, I'm new in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

`include_null_values` appears to be syntax [specific to Microsoft SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/include-null-values-in-json-include-null-values-option?view=sql-server-ver16).

In PostgreSQL this is unnecessary, because the default is to retain keys that have null values.

You may optionally remove such keys with a function `jsonb_strip_nulls()`, which is documented in this page: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

> `jsonb_strip_nulls ( jsonb ) → jsonb`
>
> Deletes all object fields that have null values from the given JSON value, recursively. Null values that are not object fields are untouched.

Comment: thank u for that, currently investigating why I not able to pull data with null values, may need to look more. we just integrated with ms SQL so this is all new to me